# Perl Dynaloader gives Usage error while calling function with parameters

Tags: linux, perl, shared-libraries

Using the Perl Dynaloader module we are loading a .so file and using "DynaLoader::dl_find_symbol" to find the symbols and install it using "DynaLoader::dl_install_xsub" finally we are calling the function as &ExConfig_fnInitialize('', 0, 1, 5, 1).

The above steps work in all Linux machines with the below configuration

RedHat Linux 3.10.0-1160.42.2.el7.x86_64

Perl 5.16

We newly created a maching with below configuration then the script giving "Usage: ExConfig::fnInitialize(szLogFileName, nFileLevel, bLogToConsole, nConsoleLevel, bUsePipe) at ./Services.pl line 807." for all parameterized function.

RedHad Linux 5.4.17-2102.201.3.el8uek.x86_64 (Redhad 8.x)

Perl 5.26

I can reproduce the error in the working environment by removing any of the parameters in the function call.

So, anyone please shed some light on why it is giving "Usage" error even we hard code the function parameters.

Comment: As a workaround, I think you can also do the same with [FFI::Platypus](https://metacpan.org/pod/FFI::Platypus)

Comment: *"we are loading a .so file"* Which library is this? Is it specific to this library, or do you get the same error with other libraries also?

Comment: @Håkon Hægland it is an in-house c++ library to do some customized tasks using Perl. Also, I cannot change the module now again not sure whether it is because of the Dynaloader.pm or any Linux library/path issue

Comment: @ikegami actually it was developed nearly 15 years ago and used in so many places/environments so, it is not possible to change the module suddenly.

Comment: The error is coming from the .so, so not sure what you expect us to do given the complete lack of information. You need to provide a minimal, runable demo of the problem as required.

Comment: Finally, if we downgrade the Perl to 5.16 then it is working but still not sure how to make it work in Perl 5.26. Thanks to all

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/XSLoader is an alternative to Dynaloader that you may want to look into, but I suspect the .so file is incompatible with your Perl 5.26 for some reason. Different architecture possibly? (32-bit vs 64-bit?) Or possibly Perl 5.26 was compiled with a different compiler or with different compiler options? If that's the reason, compiling your own Perl 5.26 using the same compiler or compiler options used to compile Perl 5.16 may allow you to use this 15-year-old library. Careful examination of the output of `perl -V` of the two Perl versions may be illuminating.